# Utilizar Método de uma classe definido em um executavel

Tags: c++

Tudo bem galera?
Estou aqui implementado algumas funcionalidades a um servidor de um jogo, eu possuo o arquivo PDB em que posso procurar os OFFSETS.

Consegui referenciar as funções globais pelo OFFSET desse jeito :

```
Arquivo .cpp
pXXX YYY = (pXXX) 0x00403B7F;

Arquivo .h
typedef <tipo_retorno_função>(*pXXX)(<parâmetros>);
extern pXXX YYY;
```

O Problema aconteceu na hora que fui tentar referenciar um método de uma classe.
Pelo que andei lendo, parece que é diferente a maneira de se fazer isso, mas o que não entendi foi : 
Quando tentei referenciar os métodos da Classe 1 do jeito que descrevi eles funcionaram corretamente, mas quando fiz na Classe 2 o executável simplesmente deu "**crash**". Um detalhe é que a Classe 1 não tem construtor e a Classe 2 sim, todos métodos são públicos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar deixar esse método que você precisa utilizar na classe 2 como static, assim, não é preciso instanciar a classe para utiliza-lo, basta colocar o nomeDaClasse.NomeDoMetodo.A linguagem c++ trata de maneira diferente classes modelo e classes que representam programas, não sendo possível instancia-las

Comment: Estou tentando chamar esse método diretamente no executável, eu apenas tenho o offset.
As modificações que estou implementando estão em uma DLL que hookei.